# In gradle copy task, 'expand' do not work in separate into blocks

Tags: gradle

I wanted to copy different files from the same source dir (from) to the same destination (into) but each one of them had a different expand.

```
myCopy(Copy) {
    from xxx
    into yyy

    into ('') {
        include "myFilename"
        rename ...
        expand('lang': $.resources.xxx )
    }
    ... similar into blocks for other files ...
}
```

Sadly the files where neither renamed nor expanded.
I solved the rename issue by moving it outside the into section since it was the same pattern for all files.
However, I could not fix the expansion.

Note: I needed to use an empty into('') to create the blocks.

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed the issue by creating "from" blocks instead of "into" blocks.
The "expand" seems to be working only on that kind of blocks.

```
from (xxx){
    include "myFilename"
    expand('lang': $.resources.xxx,'numberOfInstances': '1' )
}
... similar blocks for other files...
```

If anyone has a better solution or explanation please share your knowledge :-)